# Asterisk next to channel entry title

Tags: channel-entries

When I review channel entries from the admin control panel, menu: "Content->Edit->Channel Name", some entries in the list have an asterisk at the end of the title. What does this mean?

Comment: I misunderstood the question and have deleted my answer as a result.

Answer (score 3):

If an entry has auto-saved data which hasn't been saved manually yet, the entry will be marked with the asterisk you're seeing.